# Error is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'ROOT' does not exist

Tags: java, jdbc, syntax-error, derby

i am creating desktop application which uses derby embedded database, although when i use derby as a client database then it works fine, but i want to embed this database with my desktop application then it throws error 
below is the code for help, check it out

```
public class TaxInvoice extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 //String connectionurl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/embdIDA1db";

 String connectionurl = "jdbc:derby:embdIDA1db;create=true;user=root;password=root";

 Connection conn = null; 

 ResultSet rs;

 String po_no = null;

/**
 * Creates new form TaxInvoice
 */
public TaxInvoice() {
    initComponents();
    String dt = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    cur_date.setText(dt);
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,"root","root");
        String sql="Select * from IMPORTED_CSV";
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = s.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            po_no = rs.getString("PO_NO");
            jTextField1.setText(po_no);
        }
        rs.close();
        s.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error is"+e);
    }
}
```

and the error is

```
Error isjava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'ROOT' does not exist
```

Comment: Don't use 'quote formatting' for code!

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for make my code good for ask

Comment: You have to issue a CREATE TABLE statement to created the IMPORTED_CSV table before you can select from it. Also, to get more information about what's going wrong on the Derby side: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain And learn to find your derby.log file on disk and read it, it will have more information, particularly if you run with -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true.

Comment: **when i use derby as a client database then it works fine, but i want to embed this database with my desktop application then it throws error**
1. cd /home/path-to-dist
2. copy your db to path-to-dist folder. ie. /home/path-to-dist/embdIDA1db
3. java -jar app.jar

Answer (score 1):

Your connectionURl should be `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/embdIDA1db` which seems to be commented out in your code.

Your are passing username and password explicitly so there is no need to include them in url.

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,"root","root");
```

Comment: actually that url is for client side connection but i want my database  is to be embedded with my application so that i use it at any other system i want

Comment: yes but it still throws same error

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this.

```
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/embdIDA1db;create=true;user=root;password=root";
```

Comment: actually that url is for client side connection but i want my database  is to be embedded with my application so that i use it at any other system i want

Answer (score 0):

To make this work,
use default schema for derby
i.e. user="App" password = ""

eg :

```
       try 
        {
            // Configures and loads Database
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true", "APP" , "");

        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

or you can create schema using

```
CREATE SCHEMA <schema name>
```