# What is a best way to give connection string for derby database?

Tags: java, derby

I am trying to connect derby database and inserting some value to the table.for that i use the bellow code.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/raptor;create=true","root","root");
if (con != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to database - mydb");
}
Statement st=con.createStatement();
String q="insert into VINOTH values(7)";

st.executeUpdate(q);
```

In the above code when calling `getConnection` method I give database user "root" and password as "root", but it gives me the error

> Schema 'ROOT' does not exist

Actually root was a database user but it takes as a schema. Why is this happening?

If I give "APP" instead of database user "root" it is working fine. But I need to know why it doesn't take my user and password.

Comment: Maybe root user had only priviledges to root schema?

Comment: Duplicate of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854122/error-is-java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-schema-root-does-not-exist

Comment: Another good question/answer about the relationship between the username and the default schema is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15735068/193453